# ja.traducir.win と ru.traducir.win の内容が入れ替わっている

Tags: バグ, 再現性なし, 翻訳, traducir.win

### 不具合事象

[ja.traducir.win](https://ja.traducir.win/) へアクセスすると、 [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win/) に接続されます。string の検索結果や、ユーザ一覧などもロシア版のものになっており、スタック・オーバーフローの string やユーザは表示されません。

一方で [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win/) に接続すると、 [ja.traducir.win](https://ja.traducir.win/) の内容が表示されます。この場合でも同様に、 string の検索結果やユーザ一覧などは日本語版のものになっています。

---

### アーカイブ

#### ja.traducir.win にアクセスした場合

- https://web.archive.org/web/20191226054109/https://ja.traducir.win/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20191226054344/https://ja.traducir.win/users

#### ru.traducir.win にアクセスした場合

- https://web.archive.org/web/20191226054728/https://ru.traducir.win/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20191226055011/https://ru.traducir.win/users

Comment: 今現在、私の環境からは正常にアクセス出来ています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cubick さんのコメントによれば、この不具合は1時間程度で直ったようで、現在こちらでも修正されていることが確認出来たため、この回答で解決済みとします。

いったいなんだったのだろうか...。